# How to start an interactive java app with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, kotlin

I want to write a gradle task that runs me this small application:

```
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

class TestApp{
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args:Array<String>){
            val a = try{
                args[0].toInt()
            }catch (e:Exception) {throw argException}

            val b = try{
                args[1].toInt()
            }catch (e:Exception) {throw argException}

            print("$a + $b = ")
            val answer = readLine()!!.toInt()

            println(if(a+b == answer)"CORRECT" else "WRONG!")
        }

        private val argException:IllegalArgumentException by lazy { IllegalArgumentException("expecting two integers as args") }
    }
}
```

If I run the application with, say, Intellij, the app will pause at the `readline()` and expect user input.

However, if I add a gradle task for it

```
task runTestApp(type:JavaExec){
    main = "${javaMainTestApp}"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

and run, say,

```
gradle runTestApp --args="2 4"
```

Then I get

```
2 + 4 = Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at [...].app.TestApp$Companion.main(TestApp.kt:19)
        at [...].app.TestApp.main(TestApp.kt)
```

Why is that? And more importantly, how do I get the execution to wait for user input?

***UPDATE***

Thanks @tim_yates:

adding `standardInput = System.in` makes the app accept user input

but results in an output like:

```
3 + 5 =
<<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [20s]
> :runTestApp
8
```

where 8 is the user input.

consequently, when the app finishes, the output reads

```
3 + 5 =
<<======CORRECT> 80% EXECUTING [22s]
```

Comment: Inside your task, can you try adding `standardInput = System.in`

Comment: @tim_yates yup, that seems to wait for it, thank you. You wouldn't know how to get rid of the progress bar (see update above)?

Comment: Try with `--console=plain`

Comment: can you please formally describe WHERE you added "standardInput = System.in"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and do a `gradle run`. Or you could use the [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) and run the script.